# MySQL limit on 2nd join in query

Tags: mysql, join, limit

I'm not sure how to limit a second join in a query. In a [fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/81be2b/7/0) prepared by me I need to limit the number of rows per user in the result.

table a:

```
id | word
----------
1  | xyz
2  | zzz
```

table b:

```
name  | word
------------
Peter | xyz
John  | xyz
Jane  | xyz
```

table c:

```
name  | product
------------
Peter | blah
Peter | blah2
Peter | blah3
Peter | blah4
Peter | blah5
Peter | blah6
John | hello
John | world
John | blah
```

Desired result: first two entries of table b (user Peter and John) and first two entries joined on table c per user.

```
name  | word | product
----------------------
Peter | xyz | blah
Peter | xyz | blah2
John  | xyz | hello
John  | xyz | world
```

My current query is

```
select c.name, first_join.word, c.product from (
select b.* from a
left join b on b.word=a.word
where a.id=1
limit 2
) first_join
left join c on c.name=first_join.name
```

It yields the result:

```
name  | word | product
------------------------------
Peter | xyz  | blah
Peter | xyz  | blah2
Peter | xyz  | blah3
Peter | xyz  | blah4
Peter | xyz  | blah5
Peter | xyz  | blah6
John  | xyz  | hello
John  | xyz  | world
John  | xyz  | blah
```

Do you have any ideas? I've found another thread discussing the issue, but I wasn't able to map that to my case. I know that the structure is not perfect, but I'm not allowed to change the design of table c.

Comment: Please include the code in question too.

Comment: If I had the same task, I'd use a subquery just like you have. For all intents and purposes, subqueries are the same as joins except you can limit amount of records in a subquery. If your query works and you're ok with it - look no further. Even if you were to rewrite it, you'd get the same performance out of it ultimately.

Comment: You can try to use `union` Operator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use a stored procedure, select the distinct names, loop through the result and select 2 rows for each name.

The following stored procedure gives you the result you need (this is working on MySQL 5.6 server, but not in sqlfiddle):

```
drop procedure if exists fetch_names;

DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE fetch_names()

    BEGIN 
    DECLARE v_ready INTEGER DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE v_name varchar(100) DEFAULT "";
    -- first fetch all distinct names
    DECLARE names_cursor CURSOR FOR select distinct c.name from c;
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET v_ready = 1;

    -- use a temporary table to store results
    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE names_temp ( `name` varchar(255),  `word` varchar(255),  `product` varchar(255));

    OPEN names_cursor;

    -- loop through all names
    get_names: LOOP
    FETCH names_cursor INTO v_name;

    IF v_ready = 1 THEN 
     LEAVE get_names;
     END IF;

    -- get 2 results for each name (you may add some order parameter here)
    INSERT INTO names_temp SELECT c.name, b.word, c.product from a
    LEFT JOIN b on a.word = b.word
    LEFT JOIN c on b.name = c.name
    WHERE c.name = v_name
    LIMIT 2;

    END LOOP get_names;
    CLOSE names_cursor;

    -- output the collected result and drop the temporary table
    SELECT * FROM names_temp;
    DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS names_temp;

END$$
DELIMITER ;

-- call the procedure and get the results
call fetch_names();
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This works as expected. I had no idea it was such an effort to program such a behavior. Thought it could be done with another subquery or some other one-liner. I've never used procedures, so many thanks for the comments in the code.

Answer (score 0):

Lets dissect your query:

```
SELECT b.* FROM a
LEFT JOIN b ON b.word=a.word
WHERE a.id=1
LIMIT 2
-- This sub-query returns the following result:
+-------+------+
| name  | word |
+-------+------+
| Peter | xyz  |
| John  | xyz  |
+-------+------+
```

If without the full syntax from the sub-query, your main syntax would look like this:

```
SELECT c.name, first_join.word, c.product FROM first_join
LEFT JOIN c ON c.name=first_join.name;
```

Let's replace the `c.name, first_join.word, c.product` with `*`. Then you'll get result like this:

```
+-------+------+-------+---------+
| name  | word | name  | product |
+-------+------+-------+---------+
| Peter | xyz  | Peter | blah    |
| Peter | xyz  | Peter | blah2   |
| Peter | xyz  | Peter | blah3   |
| Peter | xyz  | Peter | blah4   |
| Peter | xyz  | Peter | blah5   |
| Peter | xyz  | Peter | blah6   |
| John  | xyz  | John  | hello   |
| John  | xyz  | John  | world   |
| John  | xyz  | John  | blah    |
+-------+------+-------+---------+
```

Now, here is where you ask yourself whether this is what you want or not? If it's not, you'll need to make sure you understand the logic of what you're trying to do here. Like for example, why does your `first_join` sub-query returns two rows but when you `LEFT JOIN` it returns all rows from `table c`? 
Well, the answer to that is because of your `ON c.name=first_join.name`. It matches all peter and john occurrences in `table c` regardless of the limit you've imposed in the sub-query. If you put limit on the outer query it won't work as well.

tl;dr
If you're using MySQL 8.0, you can try this query below:

```
SELECT name,word,product FROM
(SELECT 
    b.name, b.word,c.product,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY c.name ORDER BY c.name DESC) AS wRow
FROM 
a JOIN
b ON a.word=b.word JOIN
c ON c.name=b.name
WHERE a.id=1) r
WHERE wRow IN (1,2)
ORDER BY name DESC;
```

[Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/hoyL3Tr3NVCxfNzU2g1vGh/1)

Two other example:

```
-- First: by using INNER JOIN and UNION (as suggested in the comment).
SELECT b.name,b.word,r.product FROM a JOIN b ON a.word=b.word JOIN
((SELECT * FROM c WHERE c.name='peter' LIMIT 2) UNION
(SELECT * FROM c WHERE c.name='john' LIMIT 2)) r
ON b.name=r.name 
WHERE a.id=1;

-- Second: by using LEFT JOIN.    
SELECT b.Name,b.Word,IF(p.product IS NULL,j.product,p.product) AS 'Product' 
FROM a JOIN b ON a.word=b.word LEFT JOIN
(SELECT * FROM c WHERE NAME='peter' LIMIT 2) p ON b.name=p.name LEFT JOIN
(SELECT * FROM c WHERE NAME='john' LIMIT 2) j ON b.name=j.name
WHERE a.id=1 AND b.name IN (p.name,j.name);
```

**UPDATE:** Ok. Not pretty but this query can work. I've tested on MySQL 5.7. ;)

```
SELECT b.Name,b.Word,c.Product FROM a 
JOIN b ON a.word=b.word 
JOIN c ON b.name=c.name 
JOIN (SELECT c.name,
REPLACE(SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(product SEPARATOR ' '),' ',2),' ',',') prod 
FROM c GROUP BY NAME) r
ON b.name=r.name WHERE FIND_IN_SET(c.product,prod);
```

But it will be much easier if you have a column with autoincrement value at least.

Comment: Thank you. The first query is working in your fiddle, but unfortunately my MySQL version is 5.7, so the first query doesn't work for me. I'll check if I can update MySQL without any problems. 
I don't think that the other two examples are suitable since there are hardcoded strings in there. I was thinking more of a generalized form, e. g. using a.id=2 and above.

Comment: Yes, I figured that its not dynamic so it's not easy to use in real world environment. I have another suggestion. I'll update in my answer and see if you can use it instead.

Comment: I didn't know there were so many different approaches to reach the goal and I never used wRow and FIND_IN_SET. However, I will accept the answer from HelgeB, since it is a pretty nice solution I think. Nevertheless many thanks for the different approaches!

Comment: Yes @GioWay . It's up to you to accept which answer.. provided that it's the best practice for your environment. I am learning myself and this is one of the way I can improve so, in all honesty, this is my first time of using FIND_IN_SET myself. And as far as wRow goes, its just an alias so I think you meant this function `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY c.name ORDER BY c.name DESC)` .. is also my first time using it. ;)